# Кодировки Unicode и ASCII

Tags: unicode, ascii

Какое строковое выражение из 8 символов, которое с помощью синтаксиса экранирования символа Юникода задаёт восклицательный знак из набора ASCII? Впишите его в двойных кавычках в текстовое поле.

Не могу найти ответ на вопрос. Очень нужно, помогите пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Непонятно что курили автора вопроса. И тут явно не хватает контекста, например, о каком языке программирования идёт речь?

Comment: Курсы по JavaScript.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/string#spetssimvoly Возможно имелось в виду `"\u0021"` или `"\u{0021}"`

Comment: Первый вариант оказался верным. Спасибо большое за помощь, Алексей!

Comment: Но если вы не смогли самостоятельно ответить на этот вопрос, возможно стоить пройти/просмотреть курс ещё раз.